# ESLint configuration in ..\package.json is invalid: - Unexpected top-level property "babelOptions"

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, eslint, eslintrc, babel-eslint

i am starting new project with purchasing theme. the dependenci provide with theme has older virsion so am trying to update it with `npm update` and removie some dipendency also.
after the removing all unnesecery dependency i just hit `npm i` and `npm start` but i got this problem.

```
ESLint configuration in ..\package.json is invalid:
    - Unexpected top-level property "babelOptions".
```

i tried to solve it but did not get any answer.

thanks for help.

here is my `package.json` file.

```
{
  {
  "name": "react-hook",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
    "axios": "^1.2.1",
    "axios-mock-adapter": "^1.21.2",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.0",
    "classnames": "^2.3.2",
    "date-fns": "^2.30.0",
    "eslint": "^8.30.0",
    "firebase": "^10.1.0",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "framer-motion": "^10.12.18",
    "i18next": "^23.4.1",
    "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^7.1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "lodash.clonedeep": "^4.5.0",
    "metismenujs": "^1.3.1",
    "node-sass": "^9.0.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-calendar": "^4.6.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dropzone": "^14.2.3",
    "react-i18next": "^13.0.3",
    "react-ios-time-picker": "^0.2.2",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.6.1",
    "react-script": "^2.0.5",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "react-slick": "^0.29.0",
    "react-time-picker": "^6.5.0",
    "reactstrap": "^9.1.5",
    "redux": "^4.2.1",
    "redux-form": "^8.3.10",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-saga": "^1.2.3",
    "reselect": "^4.1.8",
    "simplebar-react": "^3.2.4",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "styled-components": "^6.0.7",
    "toastr": "^2.1.4",
    "yup": "^1.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build --max_old_space_size=8000 build",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "lint:fix": "eslint --fix .",
    "format": "prettier --write \"**/*.{js,jsx,json,md,html,css,less,scss}\"",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "eslint:recommended",
      "plugin:react/recommended"
    ],
    "babelOptions": {
      "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-react"
      ]
    },
    "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser",
    "parserOptions": {
      "requireConfigFile": false,
      "ecmaVersion": 2020,
      "sourceType": "module",
      "ecmaFeatures": {
        "jsx": true
      }
    },
    "env": {
      "browser": true,
      "es6": true
    },
    "globals": {
      "$": true
    },
    "settings": {
      "react": {
        "version": "^17.0.1"
      }
    },
    "rules": {
      "semi": [
        "error",
        "never"
      ]
    }
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "moment": "2.29.1",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint-config-standard-react": "^9.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.20.6",
    "prettier": "^2.1.1"
  }
}

}
```

and here is my `.eslintrc` file.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "no-undef": "off",
    "react/prop-types" : "off",
    "react/no-unescaped-entities": 0
  },
  "extends": [
    "plugin:react/recommended"
  ],
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 6,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true,
      "modules": true,
      "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true
    }
  }
}
```

i also try with this in `.eslintrc`

```
{
  "rules": {
    "no-undef": "off","react/prop-types": "off"
  },
  "extends": [
    "plugin:react/recommended"
  ],
  "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-react"],
    "ecmaVersion": 6,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true,
      "modules": true,
      "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true
    }
  }
}
```